# Data deleted after update

Tags: android, updates, auto-update

I have published a new update for my app but when I upgrade it from Play Store I have seen that application data were deleted. Why?
Thanks

My Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Does your app use sqlite or are you talking about simple application data?

Comment: Simple application data, I save some data into .dat files (in the /data/data/package/files)

Comment: Are you saving data as internal file storage?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi yes, into /data/data/....

Comment: share your manifest file

Comment: @ShaifaliRajput I have edited the question and added manifest file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sqlite and in code you drop table in onUpgrade this may occur!

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + DATABASE_TABLE + "'");

}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I don't use SqlLite . I only save dummy string into a .dat file